# Stoping a link from executing it's href path

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to stop a link from executing it's default action , but I seem to have no luck.Here is my code:

```
 $("a.delete").on("click", function (e) {
    var container = $("#lightbox-background");
    var lightbox = $("#lightbox");

    lightbox.init("Are you sure you want to delete this book?")
    e.preventDefault();       
});
var lightbox = {
    init : function(actionString){
        $("<div id='lightbox-background'></div>").appendTo("body");
        $("<div id='lightbox'></div>").appendTo("body");
        $("<p></p>").appendTo("#lightbox");
        $("<a href='#' id='ok'>OK</a>").appendTo("#lightbox");
        $("<a href='#' id='cancel'>Cancel</a>").appendTo("#lightbox");
    }
}
```

I hoped that if I used e.preventDefault it would stop the link from from going to it's href path but it did not work.Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** I just noticed that if I remove the call for the lightbox object from the click event handler the e.preventDefault() works.

Comment: Have you tried `return false;`? It might work.

Comment: add one more statement : return false; after preventDefault call

Comment: Try adding the missing semi colon `;` after `lightbox.init("Are you...");`.

Comment: preventDefault should be enough. Is your code executed at all? Also - do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo for your problem.

Comment: Re your edit: That means something with `lightbox.init` is wrong (`lightbox` not defined, `.init` not defined, something inside the function throws an error, ...). Have a look at the console, set breakpoints, etc. Read this to learn how to debug JavaScript: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
var lightbox = $("#lightbox");
```

in onclick callback function hide
variable name is the same as name of global lightbox object defined outside click callback. Local variable mentioned above simply override global variable inside that function scope. Basically, you are calling `init` of `$("#lightbox")`:

```
$("#lightbox").init("....")
```

Not sure what are you doing, but try to update your code like this:

```
$("a.delete").on("click", function (e) {
    var container = $("#lightbox-background");
    var lightboxElement = $("#lightbox");

    lightbox.init("Are you sure you want to delete this book?")
    e.preventDefault();       
});
```

Besides, calling

```
var container = $("#lightbox-background");
var lightboxElement = $("#lightbox");
```

at the first time, you will get an empty set of elements as init method is not executed at that moment and elements you are looking for are not created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try if it works

```
$("a.delete").on("click", function (e) {
    var container = $("#lightbox-background");
    var lightbox = $("#lightbox");

    lightbox.init("Are you sure you want to delete this book?")
    e.preventDefault();   
    return false;    
});
```

Comment: `return false;` is the same as `event.stopPropgation(); event.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it above the vars declared:

```
$("a.delete").on("click", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();        
   var container = $("#lightbox-background");
   var lightbox = $("#lightbox");

   lightbox.init("Are you sure you want to delete this book?")
});
```

Just noticed that you have missed a `';'` at closing here:

```
var lightbox = {
  init : function(actionString){
     $("<div id='lightbox-background'></div>").appendTo("body");
     $("<div id='lightbox'></div>").appendTo("body");
     $("<p></p>").appendTo("#lightbox");
     $("<a href='#' id='ok'>OK</a>").appendTo("#lightbox");
     $("<a href='#' id='cancel'>Cancel</a>").appendTo("#lightbox");
  }
}; //<----this one
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for a link like:

```
<a href="google.com"> google </a>
```

use javascript with jQuery

```
$("a").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); return false;});
```

this will not redirect any link on the page :)

or in given case it will be like

```
$("a.delete").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); return false;});
```

Note: Added `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the event from triggering.